# How to format HTML string with font for ZSSRichTextEditor?

Tags: html, ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm using following 3rd party library [**ZSSRichTextEditor**](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor) in my app. To have **Bold** *italic* and underlined text. This is working that's this library is promising. After formatting my text, I'll ask for HTML string by calling following method, `getHTML` it'll simply return me HTML form of my string.

After that, I'll need to show it into `UILabel` and `UITextView` – when I try to show those text, it's showing me the text but not with the font which I want. How do I get this done?

I'm attaching some screenshots to make things easy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

See fonts difference in screenshots 2-3.

I'm converting HTML string to attributed string and then setting it for `UITextView` or `UILabel`.

```
NSString *htmlString = [self getHTML];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
descriptionTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The editor is styled using the following:

```
* {outline: 0px solid transparent; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-touch-callout: none;}
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
body {padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; height:100%;}
```

This is the same thing that and browser does, is set some default styling for the content.